# Google Drive SDK (PHP) Children: list - How to set the query parameter

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I follow the documentation there:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list

I would like to set a query in the parameters so i tried to simply do this:

```
$parameters = array();
$parameters['q'] = "My Query";
$children = $service->children->listChildren($folderId, $parameters);
```

As written in the doc:

> Requests with children.list accept the q parameter, which is a search
>   query combining one or more search terms

But the q is not recognized, i get this error:

> An error occurred: (list) unknown parameter: 'q'

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the latest version of the PHP client library? I just tried with it and the `q` parameter is supported when listing children.

Also, make sure that the value of the `q` parameter matches the search query syntax as explained at https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters.

For instance, here is a valid children list request that specifies a query parameter:

```
$parameters = array();
$parameters['q'] = "title contains 'Drive'";
$children = $service->children->listChildren($folderId, $parameters);
```

Comment: Just a bit tricky because the i downloaded the latest library there: https://developers.google.com/drive/downloads but the Google drive service class is contrib is not there, then i checked out the repo : 
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/ and in the v2 of the lib the q parameter is not supported and then i took the class from the trunk there: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/apiDriveService.php and it's finally working :)